# Install Newtonsoft.Json not working - Error Occured

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, nuget-package

I have Visual Studio 2015 (Community 2015) and trying to install nuget-package Newtonsoft.Json
I get an error when trying to browse,

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Nuget.org deprecated TLS 1.0 and 1.1, it might be a cause of issue

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting Newtonsoft.Json Package reference from packages.config file and try again. I ran into same kind of issue once.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this... How do I deleting Newtonsoft.Json Package reference from packages.config file ?

Comment: If you have a packages.config file in your project just open it in visual studio or a text editor, you will find a line similar to this one :<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net461" /> Just delete it and try installing the package again.